# which way is best either creating dynamic page using jsp or updating current page via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

I am creating a dynamic project using jsp/servlet and ajax in my project user will fill a form and click on submit button the form will be submitted to ProcessForm servlet i want to know which way is better to show result to user either i should create dynamic web page from ProcessForm servlet or should return json object to current html page via ajax and update current page to show result to user.

please someone guide me in right way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a really good question and there are pros and cons attached. The best to me is a combination of both when done in sync.

Pros for loading AJAX JSON

- In the current web world, The UI keeps changing after some time and new refreshing UI design comes. If you have data as JSON all the UI manipulation will be done on UI and no back-end changes are required. doing changes in JSP is tedious and time-consuming.
- When JSON is loaded it's stored as an object. Hence you hold on the original data, In case if UI is manipulated or change, it's easier to go back to original view.
- With the addition of JS MVC like angular, ember etc. the extensibility and feature provided on the UI with data loaded through JSON is really rich compared to JSON.

Cons

- Though modern browser are fast, if JSON data comes in a large amount, the javascript processing of those data and creating html elements with iteration puts a load on browser (must have seen "stop script" button). Sometime browsers hangs. If you load the data through JSP it would take longer for larger data amount but most probably won't throw ugly browser alerts.
- In case data is large, you have to apply loader gif to show people to wait while data loads and processes (though it's better than blank page it's still undesirable)
- There is a limit to simultaneous ajax call (6 i guess). 7th needs to wait.
- The concept of multithreading on UI has still not caught up.

My suggestion would be to use a smart combination of both. recognize what data is plain and must be shown (in JSP), some data can be loaded on demand or through lazy loading.

P.S - The first point in Pros is an awesome reason to choose AJAX as per my experience.

Comment: JSON data is not large I need to pass only 5 to 10 kb JSON data from servlet to html and have to create only 5 to 10 html element using jquery.

Comment: That's the case for most requirement and it's strongly recommended to use ajax for such requirement.